# $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n[-(n+1)^{-1} + ln(1 + \frac{1}{n}) ]^2 }{-2n^{-3}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, logarithms, exponential-function

[Wolfram says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20as%20n%20to%20inf%20of%20%7B%20%5B(1%2B1%2Fn)%5En%5D%20%20*%20%5B%20-(n%2B1)%5E(-1)%20%2B%20ln(1%2B1%2Fn)%20%5D%5E2%20%7D%20*%20(n%5E3)%20%2F%20%7B%202%20%7D) the limit is zero, but I'm not sure how to prove this. I seem to get $\infty * 0$ when plugging in 0 and an infinite loop when applying l'Hopital's rule.

Comment: note that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=e$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n\left(-(n+1)^{-1} + \ln(1 + \frac{1}{n}) \right)^2 }{-2n^{-3}}=-\frac{e}{2}\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\left(\ln(1+x)-\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^2}{x^3}=$$
$$=-\frac{e}{3}\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\left(\ln(1+x)-\frac{x}{x+1}\right)\left(\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}\right)}{x^2}=$$
$$=-\frac{e}{3}\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\ln(1+x)-\frac{x}{x+1}}{x}=-\frac{e}{3}\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)=0.$$

Comment: In the first step, you seem to (mistakenly?) make the denominator from $x^{-3}$ to $x^3$.

Comment: @Sarah $x=\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Great answer (+1), but you skipped a lot of steps :)

Comment: In the final step, is it not the case that $\frac{ln(1+x)}{x} = \frac{0}{0}$? I don't understand how you can proceed to the next step.

Comment: @Sarah No! It's a known limit: $\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=\ln(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\rightarrow\ln{e}=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying the limit with $n^4$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1+\frac 1n)^n[-n^2(n+1)^{-1}+n^2\ln(1+\frac1n)]^2}{-2n}$$
Now using the Taylor series $\ln(1+x)=x-x^2+x^3-x^4+\cdots$ we get
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(1+\frac 1n)^n[-n^2(n+1)^{-1}+n-1+\frac1n-\cdots)^2}{-2n}$$
Now  $$-n^2(n+1)^{-1}+n-1+\frac1n-\cdots\leq -n^2(n+1)^{-1}+n=\frac{-n^2+n(n+1)}{n+1}=\frac{n}{n+1}$$
Since $(1+\frac1n)^n$ converges to $e$ and $(\frac{n}{n+1})^2$ converges to $1$ when $n$ goes to infinity the numerator converges while the denominator diverges to infinity the desired limit is $0$